# Limit number of characters in input

Tags: javascript, html, input, limit, onkeypress

How do I limit the number of characters in my input?

In the following code I want max 14 characters.

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
function SomenteNumero(e){
    var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;   
    if((tecla>47 && tecla<58)) return true;
    else{
        if (tecla==8 || tecla==0) return true;
    else  return false;
    }
}
</script>




<input type='text' size='10' value='' onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)'>
```

Comment: And the question is ? (BTW: Don't trust a user, don't trust client side validation, don't trust your coffee! Hmm, maybe the last one not, but the other two :)

Comment: The question is _where is the PHP?_

Comment: After your edit, it's still unclear, what your question is, where you are stuck..

Comment: sorry... I fumble... I'll correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with html

```
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="14">
```

If you dont trust client side validation:

```
$maxlength = 14;
$string = $_POST['string'];
if([url=http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php]strlen[/url]($string) > $maxlength) {
$string = [url=http://us2.php.net/substr]substr[/url]($string, 0, $maxlength);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML maxlength on the input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="14">
```

Comment: Do you trust client side validation ?